# Phantom keystrokes of letter "V" only

Tags: keyboard, hardware

My computer randomly types the letter "V" intermittently, even when I'm not even touching the keyboard.

I have tried two different USB keyboards and two different USB ports and it still happens. It's ONLY the letter V.

It's unpredictable. It won't happen for ten minutes and then it starts happening.

As such, code I'm checking in is littered with errant v's everywhere.

Thoughts?

```
test $ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Lite-On Technology Corp. HP Wireless Keyboard Kit id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Lite-On Technology Corp. HP Wireless Keyboard Kit id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lite-On Technology Corp. HP Wireless Keyboard Kit id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Raw Set 2 keyboard                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

**USB**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04ca:008d Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**EDIT: Interesting new wrinkle**

I just realized when I stomp on the floor or bump my desk, this triggers the phantom keystrokes of the letter V and sometimes B. So, it's clearly something physical. Internal mobo connectors maybe?

Comment: Does this happen when the keyboard is unplugged?

Comment: @Yamboy1 I actually haven't tried that. Will do, however, I tried two keyboards of different brands so my guess is that it will still happen without a keyboard.

Comment: @KirkRoss: Could you please try with a *wired* keyboard and *disconnect or disable the wireless* keyboard interface? I suspect the latter might pick up some signal that it interprets as key stroke.

Comment: I only have wired keyboards (can't stand wireless). It does it with no keyboard plugged in at all. However, I edited my question to include a new wrinkle that when I bump my desk, that triggers the phantom keystrokes. So, maybe something loose on the mobo?

Comment: @KirkRoss David was talking about this: `↳ Lite-On Technology Corp. HP Wireless Keyboard Kit id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]` line that appeared in the `xinput list`.

Comment: Try disabling it with `xinput float 12`

Comment: @Yamboy1 I am so embarrassed. As it turns out, the wireless keyboard that came with my work station was sitting on a nearby desk with a mouse sitting on top, so... any time I bumped my desk it moved the mouse sitting on my keyboard and it depressed the V key. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am so embarrassed. As it turns out, the wireless keyboard that came with my work station was sitting on a nearby desk with a mouse sitting on top-- I didn't even know it was there. So... any time I bumped my desk it moved the mouse sitting on that keyboard and it depressed the V key. 
Mystery solved!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is an extra wireless keyboard plugged in:

exerpt from `xinput list`:

```
↳ Lite-On Technology Corp. HP Wireless Keyboard Kit id=12 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

This might be the cause. You can disable it by running `xinput float 12`

Thanks to @DavidFoerster for noticing this

Comment: That was the culprit. It was sitting across the room on another desk and whenever it got bumped, the phantom keystrokes happened.

Comment: Don't forget to click the checkmark to mark this question as answered @KirkRoss